# Compare profile with a structure with R

Tags: r

I' would like to compare a profile (average appearance of a variable) with a given structure (real appearance of the variable).

The dataset looks like that for the profile P:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0.047, 0.092, 0.065, 0.091, 0.076, 0.067, 
0.087, 0.065, 0.076, 0.052), V2 = c(0.086, 0.06, 0.056, 0.076, 
0.09, 0.071, 0.075, 0.063, 0.078, 0.038), V3 = c(0.065, 0.085, 
0.097, 0.082, 0.061, 0.053, 0.073, 0.083, 0.073, 0.081), V4 = c(0.071, 
0.083, 0.091, 0.07, 0.063, 0.067, 0.107, 0.071, 0.109, 0.094), 
    V5 = c(0.102, 0.104, 0.107, 0.101, 0.12, 0.116, 0.113, 0.112, 
    0.122, 0.1), V6 = c(0.086, 0.067, 0.091, 0.08, 0.07, 0.067, 
    0.073, 0.067, 0.083, 0.081), V7 = c(0.086, 0.079, 0.095, 
    0.082, 0.093, 0.114, 0.081, 0.079, 0.078, 0.083), V8 = c(0.053, 
    0.056, 0.046, 0.058, 0.067, 0.037, 0.043, 0.057, 0.034, 0.063
    ), V9 = c(0.069, 0.065, 0.069, 0.042, 0.067, 0.069, 0.071, 
    0.075, 0.06, 0.096), V10 = c(0.067, 0.054, 0.048, 0.042, 
    0.063, 0.051, 0.045, 0.053, 0.058, 0.073), V11 = c(0.024, 
    0.044, 0.042, 0.066, 0.023, 0.051, 0.024, 0.024, 0.022, 0.044
    ), V12 = c(0.047, 0.048, 0.048, 0.04, 0.044, 0.047, 0.045, 
    0.051, 0.042, 0.052), V13 = c(0.075, 0.075, 0.056, 0.072, 
    0.053, 0.079, 0.075, 0.079, 0.06, 0.046), V14 = c(0.122, 
    0.088, 0.089, 0.095, 0.11, 0.11, 0.087, 0.12, 0.105, 0.098
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The structure looks like this:

```
structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("UH6401", "UH6402", "UH6403", "UH6404", "UH6409", 
    "UH6410", "UH6411", "UH6412", "UH6503", "UH66", "UH68", "UH6501a", 
    "UH6405a", "UH6407a")))
```

So in both cases the amount of variables are equal. Also the structure. The difference is the number in each cell. Where it is in the profiles an floating point number and the cell is binary (a variable is available or not). I would like to find now this row of the profiles matrix, which is closest to the structure row.

---

UPDATE:

Ok, maybe my description was a bit unclear and I should not use terms that have a specific meaning. Therefore I try to specify more what I try to do.
If we look at the first matrix it looks like this:

```
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14
1  0.047 0.086 0.065 0.071 0.102 0.086 0.086 0.053 0.069 0.067 0.024 0.047 0.075 0.122
2  0.092 0.060 0.085 0.083 0.104 0.067 0.079 0.056 0.065 0.054 0.044 0.048 0.075 0.088
3  0.065 0.056 0.097 0.091 0.107 0.091 0.095 0.046 0.069 0.048 0.042 0.048 0.056 0.089
4  0.091 0.076 0.082 0.070 0.101 0.080 0.082 0.058 0.042 0.042 0.066 0.040 0.072 0.095
5  0.076 0.090 0.061 0.063 0.120 0.070 0.093 0.067 0.067 0.063 0.023 0.044 0.053 0.110
6  0.067 0.071 0.053 0.067 0.116 0.067 0.114 0.037 0.069 0.051 0.051 0.047 0.079 0.110
7  0.087 0.075 0.073 0.107 0.113 0.073 0.081 0.043 0.071 0.045 0.024 0.045 0.075 0.087
8  0.065 0.063 0.083 0.071 0.112 0.067 0.079 0.057 0.075 0.053 0.024 0.051 0.079 0.120
9  0.076 0.078 0.073 0.109 0.122 0.083 0.078 0.034 0.060 0.058 0.022 0.042 0.060 0.105
10 0.052 0.038 0.081 0.094 0.100 0.081 0.083 0.063 0.096 0.073 0.044 0.052 0.046 0.098
```

Each row represent a so called profile of the variables (V1 to V14). I call the blue line a profile of the variables (Ausländer, Keine Umweltbelastung, etc.)

[image]

The sum of each row is 1, so the number in each cell is the fraction of the variable of the whole row.

Resp is a 21000 x 14 matrix, that look like this:

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
 [1,]  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   1   0
 [2,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   1   1
 [3,]  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1   0   0   1   0
 [4,]  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
 [5,]  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   0   0
 [6,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
 [7,]  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0   1   0   0   0
 [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   0   1   0   0
 [9,]  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   0   0
[10,]  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   1   0
[11,]  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
[12,]  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   1   0
[13,]  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
[14,]  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
[15,]  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   0   0
[16,]  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
[17,]  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1   1   0   1   1   1
[18,]  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
[19,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
[20,]  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
```

Each row is now a respondent an the cell entry indicates if a variable (V1 to V14) is available for him (1) or not (0). Whereas the entries in vars were average data over all respondents of a subgroup, the entries in resp are observed.
The variables represent the neighborhood structure of a group. Vars show 10 different subgroups. I would like to know, to which subgroup a respondent from resp probably belong to. Therefore I need to compare each row from resp with each row from vars. I would assume, that a respondent belong to a subgroup where the overall difference is minimal.
My first thought was to divide each row of resp by the sum of the row, but the result is not really applicable. Next I thought to weight each variable by the average profile which is:

```
aver <- c(0.0718023287061849, 0.0693420423225302, 0.0753384763664876, 
0.0827043835101492, 0.109631516692048, 0.0765927537218141, 0.0870322381232645, 
0.0515014684350035, 0.0683398169561522, 0.0554744519820495, 0.0363337127130046, 
0.0463575341160886, 0.0671060291182815, 0.102443247236942)
```

But I don't know if this works. Finally I need to compare the observed data with the average data (compare the to profiles). And assign this subgroup to a respondents which profile differs least from the subgroup average.

So the question is, what is an applicable way to produce a comparable profile from resp and how to compare both profiles...

I hope that was a bit better to understand.
Thanks for y'all help!

Comment: How do you define close? What would make a profile row close to a structure row?

Comment: @PLapointe: I just updated the description...

Answer (score 0):

In second case you have a matrix which is really a folded vector  of length `prod(dim(mtx))` whose folding is managed by its `.Dim` attribute. In the first case you have a special form of a list with length == 14 called a dataframe which, like a list has a rectangular shape, but unlike a matrix may have values of different modes: logical, integer, character, numeric, or factor. It is really a collection of named lists that are tested for equal lengths. You are talking about cells and profiles, but neither of those is  really an R term, so it's a bit unclear what your last two two questions are really asking for.

If you want a quick way to look at data-objects, try:

```
str(object-name)
```

Response: If I am understanding your update correctly you want to develop a distance measure between rows in  the first object which I am going to call "Profiles" and the second object which I am going to call "Cells". Because all the profiles row sum to 1, their mean is 1/14. You could create a matrix whose elements are 1 or 0 depending on whether  each row/col item in "Profiles"is above or below the mean. Call this "procells".

```
discrProfTF <- 0+ (profiles >1/14)
```

How you break ties may be a topic for further input appropriate to your scientific domain, which you have not offered.

There is a `dist` function which has a "binary" measure and you could apply it to:

```
cbind(discrProfTF, Cells)   # a 30 x 14 matrix

dist(cbind(discrProfTF, Cells), "binary") # a 30 x 30 lower-triangular "distance matrix"
```

And you would ignore the distances comparing different procells rows and Cells rows and just focus on the distance between procells and Cells. I think you will find other strategies applicable in the [Cluster Task View.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html)

Comment: I just updated the description. I hope it is better to understand what I'm looking for.